# MySQL - BIGINT vs INT

Tags: mysql

I'm really confused about INT and BIGINT. I want to use BIGINT in my web application and don't want to be limited to INT range.

What are the pros and the cons of using bigint? I don't plan to store more than 2^20 or even 2^15. How do I prevent zero fill (using bigint unsigned)? If I use BIGINT (10) how it will affect my application?

Comment: "How do I prevent zero fill (using bigint unsigned)" --- they are not related. "If I use BIGINT (10) how it will affect my application?" --- number in parentheses does not affect your app and how and what data is stored in any way. "I don't plan to store more than 2^20 or even 2^15. " --- what's wrong with just an `int` then? It is still 2 billions of rows to be stored.

Comment: I want to store scores from a game and don't want to be limited to 2B. So, how do I prevent zero filling? What's the difference between BIGINT (1) and BIGINT (20) then? Thank you

Comment: pros and cons. 4 vs 8

Comment: "So, how do I prevent zero filling? " --- are you sure you're using a proper term? "What's the difference between BIGINT (1) and BIGINT (20) then?" --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: I agree with Drew, INT vs. BIGINT pros and cons are the storage space needed. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't want zeros to appear before the "actual" value. I want all my values to be more >0

Comment: "I don't want zeros to appear before the "actual" value." --- and are they appearing for you? Why do you think you even have such a problem?

Comment: I never had a problem with my values but this is the first time I'm using bigint and while I was reading the mysql manual I saw that there are zeros going on the left. Are you telling me that I can use BIGINT (10) will be okay and no zeros will appear before the number if the number is lets say 8 spaces?

Comment: I'm telling you that you want to ask questions about real problems you're experiencing. First - check, second - ask if you cannot get something.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will use the same technique I used for INT and as you said I will not face any problems... I hope so... Thank you